# Inline styles working but not in style head (working on CS50 project 2)

Tags: html, css, django, css-selectors, cs50

I am working on CS50 Project 2 and have a webpage that displays active listings. I want to add some changes to the css, but it nothing happens when I add changes to the style in the head, but inline styles work. How do I make it work in the head style?

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
<head>
{% block style %}
    <style>
       .text {
           font-size: 10%;
       }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
</head>
{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    {% for listing in listings %}
        <img src ="{{ listing.image }}" style = "height: 10%; width: 10%;">
        <h4 class = "text" style = "color: aqua;">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
        <h6>Description: {{ listing.description }}</h6>
        <h6>Category: {{ listing.category }}</h6> 
        <h6>Price: ${{ listing.bid }}</h6>
        
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the code. The font size doesn't change, but it will change colors because of the inline style.

If I add the color style to the head style, not in the inline, nothing happens. This is that code.

```
<head>
{% block style %}
    <style>
       .text {
           font-size: 50%;
           font-family: fantasy;
           color: aqua;
       }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
</head>
{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    {% for listing in listings %}
        <img src ="{{ listing.image }}" style = "height: 10%; width: 10%;">
        <h4 class = "text">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
        <h6>Description: {{ listing.description }}</h6>
        <h6>Category: {{ listing.category }}</h6> 
        <h6>Price: ${{ listing.bid }}</h6>
        
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this code the style does not change at all.

This is the html code that is rendered.

```
{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    {% for listing in listings %}
        <img src ="{{ listing.image }}" style = "height: 10%; width: 10%;">
        <h4 class = "text">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
        <h6>Description: {{ listing.description }}</h6>
        <h6>Category: {{ listing.category }}</h6> 
        <h6>Price: ${{ listing.bid }}</h6>
        
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, default font size is 16px, so 10% font size will be 1.6 px, and because it's acqua it will be barely visible on a white background, a small acqua line essentially

Comment: Nothing is happening for me. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: From what I see in your question your code should work, if you add more information to your question I might be able to help more

Comment: Would adding the views help?

Comment: `def index(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
        "listings": Listings.objects.all()
    })`                                                                                                                                                 This is the views code, @Zach Jenz

Comment: That doesn't really help too much, you can actually edit the question as many times as you want on here (better way of adding info). I'll post a answer and improve that with your question until your problem is solved

Comment: Ok this is clearly a django issue then (which I know little about), https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial06/ might help you, it seems as though {% block style %} is not doing what you want. Try removing the tags/using some other django block

Comment: Can you add the html that gets rendered?

Comment: @DiegoCuadros I added the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a Django template, you can link a stylesheet stored in a static file folder. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLL4KzFMfVw) is a video that explains how to do it.